# How to control serialization of visual desinger properties in Xamarin for iOS

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin

In Xamarin for iOS, I have a view which inherits from `UIView`, that is set up as follows:

```
[Register("BorderView"), DesignTimeVisible(true)]
public partial class BorderView : UIView, IComponent
{
    ...

    [Export("BorderStyle"), Browsable(true)]
    public BorderStyles BorderStyle
    {
        get { return this.borderStyle; }
        set { this.borderStyle = value; }
    }

    ...

    private BorderStyles borderStyle = BorderStyles.All;

    ...
}
```

Where `BorderStyles` is an `enum` set up as follows:

```
public enum BorderStyles : int
{
    All = 0,
    Top = 1,
    Bottom = 2,
    None = 3
}
```

The issue I am having is in the visual designer (IDE is Visual Studio for Windows).  For the most part, setting the Border Style property works as intended; however, if the *default* value of `All` is specified, the designer immediately reverts to whatever non-default value was previously set (*e.g.*, `Top`, `Bottom`, or `None` as depicted below).  Selecting "*Default Value*" from the drop-down will result in `All` being selected, however this seems non-intuitive to me and indicates that perhaps I am missing something.

[image: Property being set from visual designer, unable to save selection of 'All'.]

Is there a way to control serialization in the Xamarin visual designer for iOS?

I would like it to be such that selecting `All` would save to the property value, without having to remember to select the designer-synthesized "*Default Value*" option (which gets converted to `All`).

Comment: What do you want to do ?Change the default value of 'Name'?

Comment: No, the property in question is "Border Style".  I am trying to make it when "All" is selected in the designer, that selection "sticks".  Currently, if I select "All", my selection is cleared when I navigate away to something else.  If I select "Default Value", the selection is immediately changed to "All", and the selection is saved.